# Adobe Reader 9.0 will open PDFs in browser with local admin account but not 'regular' user?

Tags: pdf, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, adobe-reader

Im trying to figure out what permission I am missing to get this to work.

Adobe Reader 9.0 allows PDFs to be viewed within an Internet Explorer 8 browsing window.  This works perfectly if I sign on to a users PC with my domain admin account.  However when the user himself logs in, Adobe will not load the PDF.

I get an error that "Navigation to this page has been cancelled"

Ive compared all the IE settings and permissions I can think of and they all match.

I'm stuck....?

Comment: If you log in as a new non-admin user, does it work as expected?

Comment: The only users that can use that feature are admins.

Comment: So all non-admin users don't have Reader embedded in IE, but all admins do?  Have you checked the "Display PDF files in my browser" Reader setting for the affected user(s)?

Comment: Yeah the 'Display PDFs files in Browser` is checked.  I've unchecked and rechecked for the user too and no luck.  In going to uninstall Reader9.0 and reinstall Reader8.0 to see if that may fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleted the user's Windows profile.

All is good in the world again.